# Match all logic rules with a matrix and in the same order

Tags: r, matrix, sequence, rules

For example, I have a matrix like this

```
dat <- cbind(1:10,11:20,21:30)
colnames(dat) <- paste0("x",1:ncol(dat))
dat
      x1 x2 x3
 [1,]  1 11 21
 [2,]  2 12 22
 [3,]  3 13 23
 [4,]  4 14 24
 [5,]  5 15 25
 [6,]  6 16 26
 [7,]  7 17 27
 [8,]  8 18 28
 [9,]  9 19 29
[10,] 10 20 30
```

I also have a vector with logical rules, for example like this

```
pat <- c("x1>1 & x2>12","x3>25","x1<x3 & x3>28")
pat
[1] "x1>1 & x2>12"       "x3>25"         "x1<x3 & x3>28"
```

I need to check the matrix for the execution of the rules, and the rules should work in the same sequence in which they are specified in the vector.
For a better understanding, I will draw
[image]

As a result, I would like to get a function that takes two arguments, a matrix `dat` and a vector with rules `pat`, and returns true / false.

If anyone has a desire to help me with this, I will be very happy

**UPD======================================**

I do not always get the correct answer from the function `f1`, what could be the problem?

```
f1 <- function(pat, dat) {
  tmp <-  suppressWarnings(lapply(pat, function(x) 
    min(which( with(as.data.frame(dat), 
                    eval(parse(text = x)))))))
  tmp1 <- unlist(tmp)
  i1 <- any(sapply(tmp, is.infinite))
  if(i1) FALSE else identical(tmp1, sort(tmp1))
}
```

some fake data

```
set.seed(25641)
dat <- matrix(data = sample(10,20,replace = T),ncol = 3)
colnames(dat) <- paste0("x",1:ncol(dat))

pat <- c("x1>5","x2>x1","x3>1")

> dat
     x1 x2 x3
[1,]  4  4  7
[2,]  9  3  4
[3,]  7  9  5
[4,]  3  2 10
[5,] 10  7 10
[6,]  5  6  4
[7,]  9  9  4
```

According to the data, it can be seen that the function `f1` should return `TRUE`, but it returns `FALSE`
[image]

```
f1(pat = pat,dat = dat)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that loops over the pattern, convert the `matrix` to `data.frame`, while `eval`uating the expression, `if` there are no TRUE values after evaluation return FALSE or else check if the `unlist` `min` index is the same as the `sort`ed one

```
f1 <- function(pat, dat) {
   tmp <-  suppressWarnings(lapply(pat, function(x) 
       min(which( with(as.data.frame(dat), 
           eval(parse(text = x)))))))
   tmp1 <- unlist(tmp)
   i1 <- any(sapply(tmp, is.infinite))
   if(i1) FALSE else identical(tmp1, sort(tmp1))
 }
   
f1(pat, dat)
#[1] TRUE
```

For the updated

```
pat <- c("x1>1 & x2>12","x3>25","x1<x3 & x3>48")
f1(pat, dat)
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: @mr.T So if there is any column that is not in the data, it should return FALSE as well, right

Comment: I made a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68625542/match-all-logic-rules-with-a-dataframe-need-super-fast-function

Answer (score 1):

Note this will return `FALSE` if one or more of the conditions are not met

```
f <- function(dat, pat){
  list2env(as.list.data.frame(data.frame(dat)), environment())
  m <- do.call(cbind, lapply(pat, function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
  ifelse(all(apply(m, 2, any)), Reduce("<", apply(m, 2, which.max)), F)
}
```

**Output**

```
pat <- c("x1>1 & x2>12","x3>25","x1<x3 & x3>28")

f(dat, pat)
[1] TRUE


pat <- c("x1<1 & x2>12","x3>25","x1<x3 & x3>28") # first condition not met

f(dat, pat) 
[1] FALSE
```