# sequence design trees (Is there such a package or code)

Tags: r, tree, sequence, data-mining, rules

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481726/match-all-logic-rules-with-a-matrix-and-in-the-same-order) I asked the question of how to search for the triggering of a sequence of rules in the feature matrix

I am wondering if there is a way to find / generate rules like this automatically..

For example, I have data

```
make.fake.data <- function(){
X <- round(matrix(runif(20,5,10),ncol = 4),1)
colnames(X) <- paste0("var",1:ncol(X))
return(X)}
set.seed(99)
li <- list() # data
for(i in 1:3){
  X <- list( dat = make.fake.data() , target = sample(c("yes","no"),1) )
  li <- append(li, list(X))
}
li
```

each `li` fragment has a matrix of features and a target

```
   [[1]]
[[1]]$dat
     var1 var2 var3 var4
[1,]  7.9  9.8  7.7  8.2
[2,]  5.6  8.4  7.5  6.8
[3,]  8.4  6.5  6.0  5.5
[4,] 10.0  6.8  8.2  5.5
[5,]  7.7  5.9  8.4  5.9

[[1]]$target
[1] "NO"


[[2]]
[[2]]$dat
     var1 var2 var3 var4
[1,]  5.4  5.0  6.6  8.5
[2,]  9.1  9.1  6.7  9.1
[3,]  8.0  5.0  7.7  8.0
[4,]  8.9  6.0  5.2  9.9
[5,]  6.8  7.5  7.2  9.3

[[2]]$target
[1] "YES"


[[3]]
[[3]]$dat
     var1 var2 var3 var4
[1,]  8.9  7.1  8.8  7.7
[2,]  9.7  7.9  9.9  9.6
[3,]  7.4  5.6  6.5  6.9
[4,]  9.6  8.5  9.3  9.6
[5,]  6.8  9.1  5.4  6.4

[[3]]$target
[1] "YES"
```

I would like to generate rules like this
[image]

These rules do not use indexes in the matrix, only the sequence of events

Is there a package or code that can create such rules?

**UPD===========================================**

Thanks for your answer, I know about this method, but this method does not take into account the sequence of occurrence of the rules, and this is very important for me.

I'll try to clarify ..
I'm looking for a method that looks like a "sequence of association rules" but in the form of ordinary logical rules

Any way, if I do not receive the desired answer, I will return the reward to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be numerous such rules and it's not clear if you want some particular properties to be present in the rules. However, you can try a decision tree package in R to generate rules (the rules are probabilistic, in the sense that they may not true for 100% of the time) using supervised machine learning (classification), as shown in the code below:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
df <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(li)) {
  df1 <- cbind.data.frame(li[[i]]$dat, y=li[[i]]$target)
  df <- rbind(df, df1)
}
rpart(y~.,df, control=rpart.control(minsplit=2,cp=0.001))

# node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
#  * denotes terminal node

# 1) root 15 5 yes (0.33333333 0.66666667)  
#  2) var4< 6.15 3 0 no (1.00000000 0.00000000) *
#  3) var4>=6.15 12 2 yes (0.16666667 0.83333333)  
#   6) var2>=9.45 1 0 no (1.00000000 0.00000000) *
#   7) var2< 9.45 11 1 yes (0.09090909 0.90909091)  
#    14) var1< 6.2 2 1 no (0.50000000 0.50000000)  
#      28) var1>=5.5 1 0 no (1.00000000 0.00000000) *
#      29) var1< 5.5 1 0 yes (0.00000000 1.00000000) *
#    15) var1>=6.2 9 0 yes (0.00000000 1.00000000) *

prp(tr)
```

[image]

As you can see from the above decision tree (numbers rounded to 1 decimal point in the plot), a few rules generated (with 100% probability to be true on the dataset, but not necessarily order-preserving) that may be useful for you is (you may want to modify the rules according to your requirement):

> var4 < 6.15 & var2 >= 9.45 & var1 >= 6.2 : 'yes'
>
> var4 < 6.15 & var2 >= 9.45 & 5.5 <= var1 < 6.2: 'yes'
>
> var4 < 6.15 & var2 >= 9.45 & var1 < 5.5: 'no'