# Match all logic rules with a dataframe (need super fast function)

Tags: r, function, rules

I have a function that checks for the presence of logical sequences in a dataframe

```
fu <- function(dat , rule , res.only=T){
debug.vec <- rep("no",nrow(dat)) # control of rule triggers
rule.id <- 1 # rule number in vector
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  # check if the rule "rule[rule.id]" has worked on this "i" index in dat[i,]
  current_rule <- with(data = dat[i,] , expr = eval(parse(text = rule[rule.id]))  )
   if(current_rule){  # if the rule is triggered
          debug.vec[i] <- rule[rule.id]
          if(  rule.id==length(rule)  ) break   # stop if there are no more rules
           rule.id <- rule.id+1  # go to the next rule
           }}  
if(!res.only)  return(  cbind(dat,debug.vec)  )  
return(  sum(debug.vec!="no")==length(rule)   )
}
```

for example i have some data

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = sample(10,30,replace = T),ncol = 3))
colnames(dat) <- paste0("x" ,1:ncol(dat))
```

..

```
dat
   x1 x2 x3
1   3  5  9
2   3  3  3
3  10  9  4
4   2  9  1
5   6  9  7
6   5  3  5
7   4  8 10
8   6 10  7
9   9  7  9
10 10 10  9
```

there is also a vector with rules

```
rule <- c("x1>5 & x2>2" , "x1>x2" , "x3!=4" )
```

the function checks if there is such a logical sequence in the dataframe and gives a logical answer

```
> fu(dat = dat, rule = rule, res.only = T)
[1] TRUE
```

or you can change the flag `res.only = F` and see where the sequence was in the `debug.vec` column

```
> fu(dat = dat, rule = rule, res.only = F)
   x1 x2 x3   debug.vec
1   3  5  9          no
2   3  3  3          no
3  10  9  4 x1>5 & x2>2
4   2  9  1          no
5   6  9  7          no
6   5  3  5       x1>x2
7   4  8 10       x3!=4
8   6 10  7          no
9   9  7  9          no
10 10 10  9          no
```

I need the fastest possible version of this function, perhaps using the **Rccp package** or something like that..

**UPD=======================**

the `Waldi` function is not working identically to my function, something is wrong

**UPD_2_====================================**

```
# Is this correct?
```

Yes, this is correct if the rule[k] is triggered then the search for rule[k+1] starts with a new row of dat

[image]
forgive me for not being precise enough in my question, this is my fault

my function returned `FALSE` because the last rule `"x3!=4"` did not work, it should be

```
dat <- structure(list(x1 = c(2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 9L), 
                      x2 = c(2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 4L), 
                      x3 = c(4L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 10L)),
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
dat
rule <- c("x1>5 & x2>2" , "x1>x2" , "x3!=4" )

my_fu(dat = dat, rule = rule, res.only = F)
```

only two rules worked

```
> my_fu(dat = dat, rule = rule, res.only = F)
   x1 x2 x3   debug.vec
1   2  2  4          no
2   5  1  9          no
3   1  6  8          no
4   3 10  7          no
5   9  8 10 x1>5 & x2>2
6   2 10  1          no
7   6 10  2          no
8   3  4  8          no
9   3  6  3          no
10  9  4 10       x1>x2
```

it should be

```
> my_fu(dat = dat, rule = rule, res.only = T)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: In your exmaple output, why doesn't row 5 satisfy `rule[1]` ? e.g. - `library(data.table); setDT(dat)[ eval(parse(text = rule[1] ) )]`

Comment: Hello! Because 'rule[1]' has already worked on index 3 and from this moment we are looking for rules 'rule[2]' and so on ..
The answer at index 5, the rule 'rule[1]' did not work because the algorithm by that time was looking for the rule 'rule[2]'

Comment: I am taking the `rcpp` and `c++` labels off here.  This is likely a question for `data.table` or maybe `collapse` . And SO is not a 'ask for someone to write code for me' service ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

As per your update, I wrote a new `fu` function, i.e., `TIC_fu()`

```
TIC_fu <- function(dat, rule, res.only = TRUE) {
  m <- with(dat, lapply(rule, function(r) eval(str2expression(r))))
  idx <- na.omit(
    Reduce(
      function(x, y) {
        k <- which(y)
        ifelse(all(k <= x), NA, min(k[k > x]))
      }, m,
      init = 0, accumulate = TRUE
    )
  )[-1]
  if (!res.only) {
    fidx <- head(idx, length(rule))
    debug.vec <- replace(rep("no", nrow(dat)), fidx, rule[seq_along(fidx)])
    return(cbind(dat, debug.vec))
  }
  length(idx) >= length(rule)
}
```

and you will see

```
> TIC_fu(dat, rule, FALSE)
   x1 x2 x3   debug.vec
1   2  2  4          no
2   5  1  9          no
3   1  6  8          no
4   3 10  7          no
5   9  8 10 x1>5 & x2>2
6   2 10  1          no
7   6 10  2          no
8   3  4  8          no
9   3  6  3          no
10  9  4 10       x1>x2

> TIC_fu(dat,rule)
[1] FALSE
```

**For benchmarking**

```
> microbenchmark(
+   TIC_fu(dat, rule, FALSE),
+   fu(dat, rule, FALSE),
+   unit = "relative"
+ )
Unit: relative
                     expr      min       lq     mean   median     uq      max
 TIC_fu(dat, rule, FALSE) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000 1.000000
     fu(dat, rule, FALSE) 4.639093 4.555523 3.383911 4.450056 4.3993 1.007532
 neval
   100
   100
```

---

## Previous Answer

Here are some options similar to what [@Waldi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68656382/12158757) has done, but the only difference is among `parse`, `str2lang` and `str2expression`

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  any(with(dat, rowSums(sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(parse(text = rule))))==length(rule))),
  any(with(dat, rowSums(sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(str2lang(rule))))==length(rule))),
  any(with(dat, rowSums(sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(str2expression(rule))))==length(rule))),
  any(with(dat, eval(str2expression(paste0(rule,collapse = " & ")))))
)
```

and you will see

```
Unit: microseconds
                                                                                                  expr
   any(with(dat, rowSums(sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(parse(text = rule)))) ==      length(rule)))
       any(with(dat, rowSums(sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(str2lang(rule)))) ==      length(rule)))
 any(with(dat, rowSums(sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(str2expression(rule)))) ==      length(rule)))
                                  any(with(dat, eval(str2expression(paste0(rule, collapse = " & ")))))
  min   lq    mean median     uq   max neval
 94.0 98.6 131.431 107.35 121.90 632.7   100
 37.5 39.2  48.887  44.05  48.50 174.1   100
 36.8 39.6  51.627  46.20  48.45 241.4   100
 12.7 15.8  19.786  17.00  19.75  97.9   100
```

Comment: @mr.T See my udpate

Comment: @mr.T If you want the speed. you may have to resort to  Cpp. I am sorry I am not familiar with Rcpp, so this is what I can do so far.

Comment: @mr.T I found your R code is sufficiently efficient even with large `dat` (many rows), and outperforms mine. If you want higher speed, I guess you should try Cpp, rather than any R code.

Comment: Hi Thomas, please check my question if you have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867191/find-a-sequence-of-rules-in-a-dataframe-with-break-rules

Comment: @mr.T You can see my answer to your question there.

Answer (score 4):

A possible simple base R way:

```
with(dat,sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(parse(text = rule))))

      x1>5 & x2>2 x1>x2 x3!=4
 [1,]       FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [2,]       FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [3,]        TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [4,]       FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [5,]        TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [6,]       FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [7,]       FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [8,]        TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [9,]        TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[10,]        TRUE FALSE  TRUE

any(rowSums(with(dat,sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(parse(text = rule)))))==length(rule))
[1] TRUE
```

Performance :

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(any(rowSums(with(dat,sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(parse(text = rule)))))==length(rule)),
                               fu(dat = dat, rule = rule, res.only = T))

Unit: microseconds
                                                                  expr     min       lq    mean   median
 any(with(dat, sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(parse(text = rule)))))  93.201  97.7010 127.817 104.9010
                              fu(dat = dat, rule = rule, res.only = T) 465.902 499.7015 611.827 523.2505
       uq      max neval
 124.8010  834.201   100
 643.2015 2018.500   100
```

Other test:

```
dat <- structure(list(x1 = c(2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 9L), 
    x2 = c(2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 4L), x3 = c(4L, 
    9L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

dat

   x1 x2 x3
1   2  2  4
2   5  1  9
3   1  6  8
4   3 10  7
5   9  8 10
6   2 10  1
7   6 10  2
8   3  4  8
9   3  6  3
10  9  4 10

with(dat,sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(parse(text = rule))))
      x1>5 & x2>2 x1>x2 x3!=4
 [1,]       FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,]       FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [3,]       FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [4,]       FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [5,]        TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [6,]       FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [7,]        TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [8,]       FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [9,]       FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[10,]        TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

any(rowSums(with(dat,sapply(rule, function(rule) eval(parse(text = rule)))))==length(rule))
[1] TRUE

fu(dat)
fu(dat = dat, rule = rule, res.only = T)
[1] FALSE
# Is this correct?
```

Comment: Good answer! Upvoted! You can try `str2lang` or `str2expression` instead, which may give your more options :)

Comment: See my edit with new data set : the function I propose seems to fullfil the rules? Please note that I edited the Waldi_fu, I had a copy/paste error in the last bit

Comment: HiI I answered your question "# Is this correct?" in my new update